# Python - Find index of given element in list using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, indexing

```
def ind(e, L):
    if e not in L:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + ind(e, L[:1]) 
assert ind(42, [55, 77, 42, 12, 42, 100])
```

I want the index(so in this case I need 2), but the code always seems to give me the numbers instead. Also I can't use the index function in Python.

Please help if you got some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def ind(e, L):
    if e == L[0]:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + ind(e, L[1:])
```